# Sprite doesn't move right when rect.x change is <1

Tags: python, pygame

It is updated using pygame groups in run
But when my x change is smaller than 1, my sprite just doesn't move
However when it is a negative value and larger than -1, it will move as intended.

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/blob.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.Rect` only accepts integer values. floating points will get rounded, and for very small values will equal 0 which is why it won't move unless it's bigger than -1 in your case.

From [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers.

Comment: I see, thank you for the comment. Is there an easy solution to this? Also how come negative floats work?

Comment: The solution is to just use integers. Negative floats work because they are converted to an integer and rounded. So -1.5 would for example -1. (Or -2 I'm not sure). But if you give it -0.1 for example, it will most likely round to 0, which is why It won't move anything.

Comment: you can define the x and y coordinates of the object in a simpler way :' self.rect.center = (x,y)',and you have to call the update function inside your main loop:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the function with Enemy.update() ? If so try to add self.rect.x by 1 instead of 0.5